# Calculating the probabilty of drawing a specific number

Tags: probability

A friend and I got into a small argument the other day, but neither of us are good enough with probability to get a definitive answer.

Say there is game with 100 participants. Each person draws a random number from a bag, the numbers being 1-100. Every person draws one number, and the number is not put back into the bag after it has been drawn. Drawing #1 wins you the lottery, and I have been given the choise of where in the line of 100 people drawing numbers I want to stand.

Question is then, where should I stand to have biggest chance of drawing #1?
We ended up concluding the probability is the same regardless of where in the line you stand, you'll always have a 1/100 chance. We arrived at this answer by using a smaller example of 4 people and 4 numbers. Intuitively though, neither of us could really accept that answer, but we can't really see any other way to look at it.

Comment: Your intuition is good, trusting that the tickets are ordered uniformly at random means that it is equally likely that any given card is in any given position.  Hence your chances are $\frac 1{100}$ regardless of where you stand.

Comment: You are right, assuming that noone knows where number $1$ is placed (which we can safely assume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the right idea. One way to see why is to calculate the odds of winning for each participant. Let's call the participants $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_{100}$.

For $P_1$, the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{100}$.

For $P_2$, the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{99}$, if $P_2$ gets to play. $P_2$ only gets to play if $P_1$ loses, and the probability that $P_1$ loses is $\frac{99}{100}$. Hence the probability that $P_2$ wins is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{1}{99}=\frac{1}{100}$.

For $P_3$ to win, $P_1$ and $P_2$ must lose. Hence the probability of $P_3$ winning is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{98}{99}\cdot\frac{1}{98}=\frac{1}{100}$.

The probability that $P_4$ wins is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{98}{99}\cdot\frac{97}{98}\cdot\frac{1}{97}=\frac{1}{100}$.

The probability that $P_5$ wins is $\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac{98}{99}\cdot\frac{97}{98}\cdot\frac{96}{97}\cdot\frac{1}{96}=\frac{1}{100}$.

For each $P_n$, the probability that $P_n$ wins will be a similar telescoping product that is equal to $\frac{1}{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

This point is often a source of confusion.

If you like, you can prove it inductively.  Small $n$ pose no difficulty, so suppose we have shown it up to collections of size $n-1$.

Now, you have a collection with $n$ tickets (and one winning one). Draw one from the lot.  The probability that it is the winning one is  $\frac 1{n}$.  If it is not the first choice then you have a collection of $n-1$ tickets with one winning one.  By the inductive hypothesis, the probability that the winning one is in any of the slots numbered $2$ to $n-1$ is now $\frac 1{n-1}$.  Thus, prior to drawing the first ticket, the probability that the winning one was in a specifed slot between $2$ and $n-1$ was $$\frac {n-1}n\times \frac 1{n-1}=\frac 1{n}$$ as desired.